# How to create one time login for a iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am doing an application which include a userlogin,only the user login then only it will redirected to the main page.But i want to do a one time login like the facebook login or ebay login that if the user singin ,the username needs to be maintain,no further login is needed,but if the application delete from the iphone then its ok.now my application needs login when the application is deleted from the iphone memeory(multitasking).How to set up a one time login for my application?
Regards
Nipin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passwords and other sensitive user data should be stored in the keychain. The API for the keychain is plain C and available by linking agains the Security framework.

This API is somewhat cumbersome to work with. I usually use the excellent Objective-C wrapper by Buzz Andersen available [at github](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security).

The normal workflow for a one time login app is to use a startup similar to this pseudocode:

```
if (stored password exists) {
   if (login with stored password succeeds) {
      exit, we are done
   } else {
      remove password from secure storage
   }
}
if (user provides new password) {
   if (login with user provided password success) {
      store user provided password in secure storage
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your great information ,But i am very Newable to this IOS sdk,so how to integrate the gitbub code to my project?Shall i simply drage these files to my app and import the which class in my Appdelegate?

Comment: @stackiphone In this case just drag and drop the `SFHFKeychainUtils.h` and `SFHFKeychainUtils.m` files into your project.

Comment: sir where did i put this code?In viewdidfinishLaunching?Thanks

Comment: @stackiphone I do not know the setup of your project so I can not give you a definitive answer. A place that is likely good for your needs could be `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of the app delegate.

Comment: @PayloW i have a loginpage which is showing tin the application startup,if the user is sucessfully logedin then only redircted to the mainpage,if the user is alredy logenin i want to directly get the mainpage.no need to show the login page.

Comment: @stackiphone It is your app. I can not, and do not want to, write it for you. I do not know how your app shows the login view, but I know that as user I would not want to see it if I already logged in. So add the login check etc., to wherever it is you already show this login view.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the KeyChainWrapper and store the password for the key as username. Since password is sensitive, it shouldnt be stored in NSUSerDefaults.

Good link: http://www.thomasverbeek.com/blog/?p=351

What you can do is store the username in NSUserDefaults and then search for password in KeyChain based on the username. If it exists you can make a restful call with the username and password.

Answer (score -3):

For this You have to use NSUSerDefaults in that save the username and passwords. When application launching take the data from NSUserDefaults and check with the code behind the screen. When user logouts then delete the values from the NSUserDefaults.

Comment: No! Never use user defaults to store sensitive data, this is as bad as storing the password in a clear text file. Instead use keychain services.

Answer (score -3):

I believe what they meant to say is each time the app launches, do a check that gets the values (*Username*, *Password* etc) from `NSUserDefaults`. If they exist, do not show the Login screen and push which view controller you wish to show. If they don't, pop up the Login screen and when the user enters their info, save the values to `NSUserDefaults` one time.

To get the values from `NSUserDefaults`, you can:

```
NSString * username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Username"];
```

Comment: My intention on posting an answer was to make it a bit more clear how to use `NSUserDefaults`.